# Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
    'data.frame':   866 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ hour      : Factor w/ 49 levels "0","-24","-23",..: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
 $ n         : num  1.558 1.179 1.213 0.815 2.752 ...
 $ id        : Factor w/ 18 levels "3","2402","4117",..: 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 ...
 $ logactive : num  7.2 6.93 6.95 6.56 7.77 ...
 $ sqrtactive: num  36.7 31.9 32.4 26.5 48.8 ...
 $ overactive: num  0.000743 0.000981 0.000954 0.00142 0.000421 ...
```

EDIT: Output using dput()

```
structure(list(hour = structure(11L, .Label = c("0", "-24", "-23", 
"-22", "-21", "-20", "-19", "-18", "-17", "-16", "-15", "-14", 
"-13", "-12", "-11", "-10", "-9", "-8", "-7", "-6", "-5", "-4", 
"-3", "-2", "-1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
"21", "22", "23", "24"), class = "factor"), n = 2.66898148148148, 
    id = structure(18L, .Label = c("3", "2402", "4117", "4721", 
    "5108", "5112", "5314", "5413", "5427", "5437", "5440", "5443", 
    "5452", "6406", "6413", "6427", "6430", "6723"), class = "factor"), 
    logactive = 0.98169730669964, sqrtactive = 1.63370207855701, 
    overactive = 0.374674621110636), row.names = 10L, class = "data.frame")
```

And am using the following code to generate a model:

```
model <- lme(n~hour, random = ~1|id, data = df, correlation = corAR1(), weights = varIdent(form = ~1 | hour))
```

But keep receiving the error:

```
Error in MEestimate(lmeSt, grps) :
   Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
```

How can I remedy this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please include your data in a more usable form, e.g. using dput() so we can help you better

Comment: @RAB have included data output for first 10 rows using dput